# Insert decimal with comma is interpreted as two values

Tags: sql, reporting-services, decimal

I'm creating an ssrs report and creating a mockdata sql script.
In the script I want to insert a decimal value like so:

```
declare @tempTable table(
  aString varchar(50),
  aDecimal decimal(5,2)
)

insert into @tempTable
values ("somestring", 1,23)
```

The values after "someString" are actually one decimal value with a comma as decimal separator. SQL interprets this as separate values though and hence throws an error about too many values for the number of columns. How to go about this?

**UPDATE**
To clarify: I'm in a region where '.' is a thousand separator and ',' is a decimal separator.
Putting it in between quotes doesn't work either. It gives me the `Error converting data type varchar to numeric` message

Comment: that would be for thousand separators. So depending on your culture: no

Comment: @BorisCallens, the thousand separators it's just a formatting separator, your data isn't store with this separator. Format it the way you want in the application that would consume this database when displying it to the user.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal and others: I've updated my OP to clarify my regional settings

Comment: Ensure that script language is set to english (I think it is already) and use 'normal' separator - dot (1.23). In our culture comma is used either, but all our scripts run in english.

Comment: How are you providing the value to your insert statement. Do you build the statement dynamically (you should not do that) or are you using a parameter of type string (don't do that either) or ...?

Comment: It's one big hardcoded script because I'm using it as a mock dataset for my MS Reporting report. Nothing I'm going to use after design fase ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify a number *as a constant* in a SQL script, you should follow SQL *syntax* rules, not locale settings. And the syntax dictates that you use a `.` as a decimal separator. As for thousand separators, they are not used at all.

Note that this is strictly about *coding* your data in a script, not *displaying* them. Displaying is where your locale settings do matter, and if they are in order you should get your output formatted accordingly: decimal separators as commas, thousand separators as periods.

Answer (score 1):

Commas are used to separate values when inserting SQL. I don't know what type of field this is, but if it is a INT or DECIMAL it won't work.

To get it working, put quotes around them, like so:

```
insert into @tempTable
values ("somestring", '1,23')
```

The best would be to:

1. If it's a decimal, use . as comma and the manipulate the string afterwards.
2. If it's a 1000-sepeartor, remove it, you can do this when displaying it

Comment: Don't know if it's a ssrs thing, but I tried the quotes and it gives me an error. Will put this in the OP too.

Comment: What type of db-field is the number? Decimal? What language are you programming this in?

Comment: It is a Decimal(5,2) and it's MS-SQL executed in reporting-services. Updated OP

Comment: As mentioned before. You CAN'T USE COMMA AS A DECIMAL SEPERATOR. You must use `1.23`. Why? Because that is how the db-type decimal is defined. Use dot as comma and manipulate the value when you output it. I am sure there are some way to replace `.` with `,`.

Comment: Hey OC, please refer to the OP. The server running the scripts is running in a culture that interprets 1.23 as 123.

Answer (score 1):

Actually add parameter solved same issue for me.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT dbo.tickets (places,date,client_id,price,trip_id) VALUES (" + PlaceQuontity.Value + ",@date "  + "," + id + "," + "@price" + "," + TripId + ")";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = TicketDate.Value.Date;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = FinalPrice;
```

Where cmd is my sql comand and finalprice is decimal.